# UIWebView Crash?

Tags: iphone

Hii Friends,

the application is that using a imageviewer of a which had placed a Ad at Bottom where when clicked will move to php registration page,when user closes the reg.View it will go back to imageviewer, as i using Three20UI Library for the PhotoViewer,

the code as follows,

```
-(void) actionCall {

if(isValue) {

    NSLog(@"removeView from WEbview");

    UIView *tmpView = (UIView *)[self.view viewWithTag:10];

    [tmpView removeFromSuperview];

    [custView removeFromSuperview];

    isValue = FALSE;
}

if(changeViewSize == 1)
{
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 365, 360, 72);
}

 }

[cusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(actionCall) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

the program crashes when closebtn is clicked, Any Solutions Plz.

Comment: Ten questions, none accepted? You have to work on that or people will stop giving you answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void) actionCall:(id)sender {
```

...

```
[cusBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(actionCall:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```